# Showing video-files from an external HD to a display

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, external-display

What's the best/cheapest devices that you can plug an external harddrive into with USB and play it on an external display via VGA/HDMI?

It should at least support AVI, but would be great if it supported MKV, MP4 and also subtitle files: SRT and SUB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Western Digital's [WD TV](http://wdc.com/en/products/homeentertainment/mediaplayers/) line of media players. They may not be the cheapest, but they're certainly one of the popular brands in this space. Their latest model is capable of Wi-Fi streaming, amongst other things, but you're better off hooking directly your HDD to get the most absolute performance.

Comment: I have a seagate HD which is similar and cheap, and it plays a huge laundry list of video formats. The interface is poor, and the remote is slow and unresponsive, but it was CHEAP.

Comment: +1 WD ones have worked well for me. Latest firmware update added more formats as well.